# Text doesn't appear on submit button

Tags: css, button, text

I am currently redesigning a website and a page is giving me a hard time because the text over the new buttons doesn't appear on Chrome and Safari.
Here is the page :

http://dev.puzzles-et-jeux.fr/fr/page/login.html

Any help would be much appreciated! Sorry if the answer is obvious maybe I'm looking too close...

Comment: Your `input` is set to `image`, but lacks an `src` attribute.

Comment: You have two errors on your page
1) - http://dev.puzzles-et-jeux.fr/themes/puzzles-et-jeux/css/button.png `not found`
2) slidemenu.js line 7;
You may wanna check them as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing to `type="button"`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, that the text simply can't fit. Either make the `font-size` smaller or the button larger.

For example, you could remove this rule:

```
.button.large { font-size: 125%; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="image" value="Identifiez-vous" class="button large red">
```

Is incorrect, `<input type="button"` is what you need.

EDIT:
Have you tried using the button element?

```
<button type="submit">Identifiez-vous</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I applied the advice received on this page, but now the buttons of the page do not work anymore, no matter what browser I'm on...